# How to combine sets of columns in a dataframe where one column may contain lists

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a source data table that has about 30 columns each for Attribute name and Attribute value (each is paired and numbered as in the table below. I need to try and combine these into just two columns. I can do this in power query (M code)  by using the list.zip function something like below.

SOURCE DATA:

| Title | Description | Attribute 1 name | Attribute 1 value | Attribute 2 name | Attribute 2 value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Title 1 | Desc 1 | Sport | NFL | Sport | NBA |
| Title 2 | Desc 2 | Size | Large, Medium | Sleeve Type | Long Sleeve, Short Sleeve |

M Code in Power Query:

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each List.Zip(
{
     {"Attribute 1 name", "Attribute 2 name"}, 
     {[Attribute 1 name],[Attribute 2 name]}, 
     {[#"Attribute 1 value(s)"],[#"Attribute 2 value(s)"]}
}))
    
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom"),
#"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), "|"), type text}),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Values", "Custom", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Custom.1", "Custom.2", "Custom.3"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{"Name", "Custom.1"}),
#"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Attribute Value", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Attribute Value.1", "Attribute Value.2"}),
#"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter1", {"Attribute Name"}, "Attribute", "Value")
in
#"Unpivoted Columns"
```

Result in Power Query:

| Attribute name | Attribute value |
| --- | --- |
| Sport | NFL |
| Size | Large |
| Size | Medium |
| Sport | NBA |
| Sleeve Type | Long Sleeve |
| Sleeve Type | Short Sleeve |

Notice that there are two primary sets of columns that need to be combined, each set containing about 30 columns. Each set is a pair (`Attribute 1 name` & `Attribute 1 value`, all the way up to `Attribute 30 name` & `Attribute 30 value`) so they need to remain matched up on the same row if that makes sense.

Also, the "value" columns may or may not have comma separated values that need to be delimited and split out as well.

Finally, there are other columns to contend with that are not really needed for the final result and could drop out.

I have been trying use either `pandas.wide_to_long` and a combination of `pd.Index` and `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples` but cannot quite get the correct statements to get this to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "*Notice that there are **two primary sets** of columns that need to be combined, **each set** containing about **30 columns**. **Each set** is a **pair** so they need to remain matched up on the same row.*" -> this bit is unclear, do you have **pairs** or more? Can your give another example?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that "Attribute 1 name" goes with "Attribute 1 value" and there are about 30 pairs of these, so up to "Attribute 30 name" & "Attribute 30 value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the relevant information in the column names, then reshape with a MultiIndex, [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
    df.columns
      .str.extract(r'\S+ (\d+) (\S+)')                              
)

out = (df.set_axis(idx, axis=1).stack(0)
         .rename_axis(columns=None)
         .add_prefix('Attribute ')
         .sort_index(level=-1)
         .assign(**{'Attribute value': lambda d: d['Attribute value'].str.split(', *')})
         .explode('Attribute value', ignore_index=True)
      )
```

Output:

```
  Attribute name Attribute value
0          Sport             NFL
1           Size           Large
2           Size          Medium
3          Sport             NBA
4    Sleeve Type     Long Sleeve
5    Sleeve Type    Short Sleeve
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It is not working, only because I think I failed to mention that my set of columns also contain other random colums (i.e. 'Description', 'Title', etc) I am getting a `KeyError: '[nan] not in index'`

Comment: @JCan OK and what should be done with those other columns? Best is to drop them before my code, eventually adding them back afterwards. Please edit your example.

Comment: I tried to just add a `.dropna()` after `.str.extract(r'\S+ (\d+) (\S+)')` in your code provided but error out: `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 202 elements, new values have 128 elements`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help @mozway I was able to get it sorted out:

Drop the un-needed columns not a part of the transforms first:

```
woo_product_list = woo_product_list.loc[:, [x for x in woo_product_list.columns if x.startswith(('Attribute'))]]
```

Apply the proposed solution by @mozway witha small addition to drop a couple extra columns:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
woo_product_list.columns
    .str.extract(r'\S+ (\d+) (\S+)'))

out = (woo_product_list.set_axis(idx, axis=1).stack(0)
     .rename_axis(columns=None)
     .add_prefix('Attribute ')
     .sort_index(level=-1)
     .assign(**{'Attribute value(s)': lambda d: d['Attribute value(s)'].str.split(', *')})
     .explode('Attribute value(s)', ignore_index=True)
     .drop({'Attribute visible', 'Attribute global'}, axis=1)
  )
```

Comment: You can [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) the columns with `woo_product_list.filter(regex='^Attribute')` ;)